# Columns to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I am working with SQL 2008 database
Im working on a report i want to display in a graph for me to do this i need to convert my results from columns into rows
Here is my query

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN (pm.mortgagestatus) = 10  then 1 end) AS Received,
SUM(case WHEN (pm.mortgagestatus) = 10 then pm.AmountRequested Else 0 END) AS [Received Amount],
COUNT(CASE WHEN (pm.mortgagestatus) = 4  then 1 end) AS Passed,
SUM(case WHEN (pm.mortgagestatus) = 4 then pm.AmountRequested Else 0 END) AS [Passed Amount],
COUNT(CASE WHEN (pm.mortgagestatus) = 5  then 1 end) AS packaged,
SUM(case WHEN (pm.mortgagestatus) = 5 then pm.AmountRequested Else 0 END) AS [Packaged Amount],
COUNT(CASE WHEN (pm.mortgagestatus) = 6  then 1 end) AS Offered,
SUM(case WHEN (pm.mortgagestatus) = 6 then pm.AmountRequested Else 0 END) AS [Offered Amount]
FROM tbl_Profile AS p
INNER JOIN tbl_Profile_Mortgage AS pm
ON p.id = pm.fk_ProfileID
```

This Query returns 
[image]

I would like the query to return like this.

[image]

This will allow me to put the data into a chart.
Any help with this is most appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use aggregation with a `case`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN pm.mortgagestatus = 10  then 'Received'
             WHEN pm.mortgagestatus = 4  then 'Passed'
             WHEN pm.mortgagestatu) = 5  then 'packaged'
             WHEN pm.mortgagestatus = 6  then 'Offered'
        END) as Mortgage_Status,
       COUNT(*) as Total,
       SUM(pm.AmountRequested) as LoanAmount
FROM tbl_Profile p INNER JOIN
     tbl_Profile_Mortgage pm
     ON p.id = pm.fk_ProfileID
WHERE pm.mortgagestatus IN (4, 5, 6, 10)
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN pm.mortgagestatus = 10  then 'Received'
               WHEN pm.mortgagestatus = 4  then 'Passed'
               WHEN pm.mortgagestatu) = 5  then 'packaged'
               WHEN pm.mortgagestatus = 6  then 'Offered'
          END);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon Thanks for taking a look at this when i use your method im getting the following error. "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation."

Comment: I think the reason for this is because its trying to bring back a NULL Value under Mortgage_Status

Comment: to fix this i added a where clause in it like so pm.MortgageStatus IN (10,4,5,6) this now works great. Thanks for all your help.